# Application Insights not displaying data from .NET6 worker service

Tags: .net, docker, backgroundworker, azure-application-insights

I am totally in despair and probably is it just a minor detail I am missing, but I cannot figure it out.

## Description

I am following [Application Insights for Worker Service applications (non-HTTP applications)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service), and here is some details.
My package references:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.15.0" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.15.0" />
```

My secret.json

```
"APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=xxxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://somewhere-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/",
  }
```

The code follows the link mentioned, but just to put it here. Program.cs

```
services.AddLogging();
services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
```

Worker.cs

```
_logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
using (_telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("operation"))
{
   _logger.LogWarning("A sample warning message.");
   _logger.LogInformation("Calling bing.com");
   var res = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://bing.com");
   _logger.LogInformation("Calling bing, status:" + res.StatusCode);
   _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Bing call event completed");
   _telemetryClient.Flush();
}
await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
```

In Visual Studio I can see events ticking in.

[image: Visual Studio Application Insights]

## Problem

After days, I have not been able to get anything to be apper in Azure Portal. I wanted one web application and some containers to report to the same log analytics and azure application insights. However, no luck so far.
The web application whom is deployed to Azure app service reports fine.
The containers are supposed to run on a local datacenter (on premise), but now I am running them in a Docker Desktop.

## Questions.

I simply have no idea how to figure out what I am missing, so it will just be a series of questions what pops into my head. Is there something blocking from Docker? Must I adjust something in Azure Portal? Do I need to set something up on my computer? Is there a settings somewhere stating that the app should not transmit to application insights because it is a development enviroment? (I could go on for ever).
I am pretty sure this has an easy answer, but Google is not my friend these days.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If they do show up in visual studio, please confirm the iKey is not empty in the emitted telemetry. I suspect the connection string isn't pickup up correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Behind the lines in your comment I read: "Nah, this should work. You have something wrong ;-)". I am almost 100% sure that it is a relatively easy fix to this, but I cannot nail it. I have tried to hardcode the InstrumentationKey into program.cs, but no. I shall go back to the absolute beginning again, and set every item up brand new, except VS and Docker....

Comment: It should. Especially since the telemetry is captured by visual studio. The iKey property of the telemetry should match the instrumentation key of the azure AI resource. If it doesn't or is empty that is an error

Comment: It turns out that the root cause of my problems seems to be secret.json. It may look like it's simply not reading it. I will never know why my hardcoding of the iKey never worked, because that code is now in a virtual heaven (or hell).... To be continued, tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

I followed the same [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service) you shared. I can be able to get all telemetry data in Application Insights. I hope you followed all the things mentioned in the document.

#### Please check below to overcome the issue

- Check your **Package References** what are all packages you are using make sure to add them to your solution.
- Make sure the **App Insights Connection settings** values should be **valid**.
- Add the **WorkerService** in your `Program.cs` like

```cs
services.AddLogging(<Your Logger Provider>);
# make sure to access of your Hosted Service
services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
```

> Note that **ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions** in this SDK is in the namespace **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService** as opposed to **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions** in the `ASP.NET` Core SDK.

- processing the Custom Operation Tracking in Application Insights

```cs
_logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
using (_telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("operation"))
{
   #_logger will be appear on Console 
   
   _logger.LogWarning("A sample warning message.");
   _logger.LogInformation("Calling bing.com");
   var res = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://bing.com");
   _logger.LogInformation("Calling bing, status:" + res.StatusCode);
  
   # _telemetryClient will be appear in Application Insights
   
   _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Bing call event completed");
   _telemetryClient.Flush();
}
await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
```

Refer usage of [Custom Operation Tracking in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/custom-operations-tracking)

Comment: Thanks, it turns out the root cause was secret.json. It simply doesn't read it and my habit from other projects make me put it in there "automatically". It still leave me with a question, why didn't it work when I hardcoded the iKey. I will never have the answer to that question because that code doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: It takes the connection string of Application Insights. So, while hardcode your Ikey you have to pass the connection String.

Answer (score 1):

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
With this method, the connection string must be part of application's IConfiguration. I am not sure if secrets.json is automatically loaded into IConfiguration.

You can confirm this by using the following snippet:

```
 var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
 aiOptions.ConnectionString = "put it here";
 services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(aiOptions);
```